# php float comparison not working

Tags: php, if-statement, floating-point, comparison

I want to change the students marks to GP so I have code like this

```
$mark=80;    
if($mark>=84.50 && $mark<=100){$GP = 4;}
if($mark>=79.50 && $mark<=84.49){$GP = 3.67;}
if($mark>=74.50 && $mark<=79.49){$GP = 3.33;}
if($mark>=69.50 && $mark<=74.49){$GP = 3;}
if($mark>=64.50 && $mark<=69.49){$GP = 2.50;}
if($mark>=59.50 && $mark<=64.49){$GP = 2;}
if($mark>=54.50 && $mark<=59.49){$GP = 1.50;}
if($mark>=49.50 && $mark<=54.49){$GP = 1;}
else { $GP = 0; }
echo $GP;
```

Expected output here is 3.67 but here I am getting 0. Can anyone explain why I am getting 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fails because your `else` only applies to the last condition. That means all the previous `if` statements have come to nothing.

You should use `elseif` to make sure that the conditions are *truly* distinct:

```
$mark=80;    
if($mark>=84.50 $GP = 4;
elseif($mark>=79.50) $GP = 3.67;
elseif($mark>=74.50) $GP = 3.33;
elseif($mark>=69.50) $GP = 3;
elseif($mark>=64.50) $GP = 2.50;
elseif($mark>=59.50) $GP = 2;
elseif($mark>=54.50) $GP = 1.50;
elseif($mark>=49.50) $GP = 1;
else $GP = 0;

echo $GP;
```

As you see, you can also dispense with the `&&` additional condition. Finally, you don’t need braces (`{}`) around a simple statement.

Answer (score 2):

Each `if` is evaluated independently. Regardless of what happens with the first couple of `if`s, you reach the last one, and since `$mark` isn't between `49.50` and `54.49`, the code enters the `else` block, and sets `$GP` to `0`. If you replace all the `if`s except the first one with `else if`s you'll get the intended logic:

```
$mark=80;    
if($mark>=84.50 && $mark<=100){$GP = 4;}
else if($mark>=79.50 && $mark<=84.49){$GP = 3.67;}
else if($mark>=74.50 && $mark<=79.49){$GP = 3.33;}
else if($mark>=69.50 && $mark<=74.49){$GP = 3;}
else if($mark>=64.50 && $mark<=69.49){$GP = 2.50;}
else if($mark>=59.50 && $mark<=64.49){$GP = 2;}
else if($mark>=54.50 && $mark<=59.49){$GP = 1.50;}
else if($mark>=49.50 && $mark<=54.49){$GP = 1;}
else { $GP = 0; }
echo $GP;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$mark=80;    
if($mark>=84.50 && $mark<=100){$GP = 4;}
elseif(abs($mark>=79.50 && $mark<=84.49)){$GP = 3.67;}
elseif($mark>=74.50 && $mark<=79.49){$GP = 3.33;}
elseif($mark>=69.50 && $mark<=74.49){$GP = 3;}
elseif($mark>=64.50 && $mark<=69.49){$GP = 2.50;}
elseif($mark>=59.50 && $mark<=64.49){$GP = 2;}
elseif($mark>=54.50 && $mark<=59.49){$GP = 1.50;}
elseif($mark>=49.50 && $mark<=54.49){$GP = 1;}
else { $GP = 0; }
echo $GP;
?>
```

Your comparision not in proper way check above code.